# PendingIntent completion

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

I record this in the service:

```
    intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity_Large.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,  0);


   
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ant_intro)
                    .setContentTitle("Anttack")
                    .setContentText("Continues")
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    //     .setPriority(2)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE);
    }

    notification = builder.build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
```

After the device goes to sleep and wakes up, a notification appears on the screen. If you click on it, the minimized activity will be restored.

How can i track completion of PendingIntent?

Maybe someone knows how to use PendingIntent.onFinished?

Comment: You want a brand new activity to fire-up when you hit the notification instead of the minimized activity? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: The same collapsed activity is restored.

Comment: It looks like the Activity which will be brought to the foreground belongs to your own app. If I understand you correctly, you need to know that the user triggered the PendingIntent from the notification versus the Activity being shown because the user tapped the launcher icon. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some `Activity` methods which will help you to find out whether the `Activity` comes to the foreground because the user tapped the notification:

[`getIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getIntent()) will give you the `Intent` which triggered `Activity` creation if tapping the notification happens when the `Activity` has to be (re)created.

Overriding `onNewIntent()` will give you access to the `Intent` responsible for re-launching an existing `Activity`. Note that you also have the opportunity to set the new `Intent` as "the" `Intent` for this `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent){
    setIntent(newIntent);
}
```

So you can put a `boolean` as `Intent` extra when creating the `Intent` for your `PendingIntent` ...

```
intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity_Large.class);
intent.putExtra("FROM_NOTIFICATION", true);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

...  and evaluate this in your code, e.g. in `Activity.onResume()`

```
@override
protected void onResume(){
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("FROM_NOTIFICATION")){
        // Activity was (re-)launched because user tapped notification
    }
}
```

I'm aware that this way you won't be able to tell when the user taps the notification a second time when the `Activity` is already up and running. Since I don't know your use case I can't tell whether this can happen or whether this would be a problem. But since you can also pass other data as `Intent` extra, it should be possible to identify each event if required.

Comment: Looks nice.  I'll try tomorrow.  the possibility of repeated notification should be.  I think that if it is possible to zero out ‘hasExtra ("FROM_NOTIFICATION")‘ in onResume(), then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case, it was enough that the `onNewIntent()` call occurs.